# Proper way to process Large number of records in React or Java

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have front end in ReactJS and backend api in Spring Boot. I have to show a drop down list with records from Api.

The scenario is i get a list of Users Ids from one end point, then for each record i have to call another api end point to get address details associated to that user ( it may have large number of records), the drop down is name of address.

My problem is if i loop through all records and get the address details, it will time out and take forever.

Can anyone suggest me the correct way to do it, Java or JavaScript.

I have read a little about observable, observer etc. but i did not get anything. Is there any concept of updating an object continuously.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you may need at least three things: (1) Build your UI display around Promises (so you can dispatch lots of them and fill them in as they arrive), (2) fire the retrieval early rather than waiting for the dropdown to be clicked, and perhaps (3) implement a bulk endpoint where you can ask something like `/addresses?user=1,2,3`. Also consider whether restricting the dropdown to addresses belonging to a particular user makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The shorter the distance the faster it can go. If you do this client side, the server has to send data on the network and then the client can process it. The best way would be to write a SQL query that does the right joins to get the data quickly. Send the processed data to client.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to handle data is by implementing some kind of a pagination. You don't need to display all of the data in one go and it will be expensive to do so. For instance, if you have 1000 items on a list which you want to fetch, you could do it by 10s or 20s depending on your preference. This way, you could minimize the number of queries. Thus, making it much faster.

[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ynpu6r) of doing that on React JS. I'm only tapping into a [Fake Online REST API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ickyrr, Thanks for reply, Can this be achieved in pure javascript ?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this in pure javascript.

Comment: Hi ickyrr, Can you tell me higher level structure and what to use like : Observable or some other functionality.

Comment: I don't know if i understand the question correctly, but you can use your current stack for now. From what I read on your post, you're using React JS, you can use Redux with Redux-thunk for now to handle asynchronous stuff. Observable is really a complex topic for me to be honest. You can do the same things with either Observables or Redux thunk but observables are more powerful. If you're just starting out, you can use Thunk for now.  So use React JS + Redux + Redux Thunk.